# Grant user write access to DNS Server (Win2k8)

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, powershell

I want to remotely manipulate DNS records via Powershell scripts and I use the following script:

```
$zone='company.local'
$dnsrecord='dummyDNSrecord.company.local'
$rec=Get-WmiObject -ComputerName ADSsrv-credential "DNS_modifiction_user" -Namespace root/MicrosoftDNS -Class MicrosoftDNS_AType -filter "containername='$zone' AND OwnerName='$dnsrecord'"
$rec.Modify($null,"10.10.1.1")
```

Unfortunately, I get an error message "Access denied" (username and password were entered correctly).

When I add the user `DNS_modifiction_user` to the group of domain admins, it works like a charm.
We have already tried to grant the group `Dns Admin` the necessary rights for the DNS server and the DNS records without success.

What kind of settings do I need to apply to the DNS server (dnsmgmt.msc) to make it work?

### Hint

If I execute the script several times with the same parameters (same `$dnsIP`), the server deletes the record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be in `DNS Admin` group *and* have admin access to the box you are making the changes on, in your case `ADSsrv`.
N.B. This is only valid as far as running remote WMI queries for `root/MicrosoftDNS` class, there are many other solutions which only require membership of `DNS Admin` group.

Comment: The rights were not immediately published to all services - There has been some delay.

Comment: Daniel: I do not need local/domain admin rights but I must be a member of the `DNS Admin` Group. As I wrote in my first statement, it took some time to inform all the services about the group change.

Comment: @Daniel - you need admin rights on destination box to run `Get-WmiObject -Namespace root/MicrosoftDNS -Class MicrosoftDNS_AType` query remotely.